# Subselect or union operations impossible to execute in HADR standby

Tags: db2, union, subquery, standby

Trying to execute some queries in a HADR database with RoS (Read only Standby) with a union operator or with a subselect, I got the error SQL1773N reason code 5.

What is the reason? they are operations that do not generate writes.

Union

```
with hist(start_time, operationtype) as (
 select start_time, operationtype
 from sysibmadm.db_history
 where operation = 'B' )
select 'delta', timestampdiff(8, current timestamp - char(timestamp(max(start_time))))
from hist
where operationtype = 'D' or operationtype = 'E'
union all
select 'delta', timestampdiff(8, current timestamp - char(timestamp(max(start_time))))
from hist
where operationtype = 'I' or operationtype = 'O'
```

Subselect

```
with hist(start_time, operationtype) as (
 select start_time, operationtype
 from sysibmadm.db_history
 where operation = 'B' )
select 'delta', operationtype, start_time, timestampdiff(8, current timestamp - char(timestamp(start_time)))
from hist
where start_time = (
 select max(start_time)
 from hist
 where operationtype = 'D' or operationtype = 'E')
```

Comment: It could be (just a guess here) that it has to materialize those sub-queries into a work file, which still counts as a "write" on the standby.

Comment: I agree with you, however this is not defined in the documentation.

Comment: The docs say "Queries on the standby database can use only SMS system temporary table spaces." which may be relevant here, would be good to check that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem specific to `sysibmadm.db_history`.
Tried the following `union all` and `subSelect` on Standby with ROS enabled, and both worked fine

```
CREATE TABLE TAB101  (
id bigint NOT NULL,
createTimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
primary key (id))

insert into tab101 (id, CREATETIMESTAMP) values 
(1, current timestamp - 35 minutes), 
(2, current timestamp - 30 minutes),
(3, current timestamp - 25 minutes), 
(4, current timestamp - 20 minutes),
(5, current timestamp - 15 minutes), 
(6, current timestamp - 10 minutes),
(7, current timestamp - 5 minutes), 
(8, current timestamp)

with tempTab101 (id, CREATETIMESTAMP) as (
  select id, CREATETIMESTAMP from tab101
)
select id, CREATETIMESTAMP from tempTab101 
where id > 1
union all
select id, CREATETIMESTAMP from tempTab101
where id <= 10

with tempTab101 (id, CREATETIMESTAMP) as (
  select id, CREATETIMESTAMP from tab101
)
select * from tempTab101
where id = (
  select id from tempTab101 where id=2
)
```